# 'Exception' is a type and cannot be used as an expression and Transaction Aborted

Tags: vb.net

I have a function here where I debug the code, the code runs properly till end and when reaching End Using it is throwing an error as Transaction Aborted and 'Exception' is a type and cannot be used as an expression. Kindly help on this issue please.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function UpdatePrescriptionStatus(ByVal prescription As Prescription, _
                                     ByRef PrescriptionHeaderID As Int64) As Boolean

Try

    Dim TransactionScopeObject As TransactionScope
    Dim PrescriptionDBObject As New PrescriptionDB
    Dim PrescriptionId As Integer

    TransactionScopeObject = New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)

    Using TransactionScopeObject
        Select Case prescription.StatusID

            Case OnlinePrescriptionStatus.PrescriptionCreated

                PrescriptionId = CreatePrescription(prescription)
                prescription.ID = PrescriptionId
                PrescriptionHeaderID = PrescriptionId
                If PrescriptionId <> 0 Then
                    CreatePrescriptionHistory(prescription)
                End If

            Case OnlinePrescriptionStatus.DoctorApproved
                'OnlinePrescriptionStatus.PrescriptionPartiallyDispensed

                If PrescriptionDBObject.UpdateDoctorAcknowledgedStatus(prescription) Then
                    CreatePrescriptionHistory(prescription)
                End If


        End Select
        TransactionScopeObject.Complete()
        Return True

    End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: There is a catch without a try in your code... based on the exception text, this might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Sorry i didnt copy paste properly, actually there is a try blow the public function.

Comment: I have written a function as close as possible to yours and am unable to reproduce the error. The only issue I see is that you never return `False` in the event of an error, but that should by no means produce the error you describe. (It certainly didn't for me.) From your description, it sounds like the error occurs at run time, not when you compile? Have you tested it with `Option Strict`? Have you passed the function both values that should not throw an exception and those that should (i.e. `Nothing`)? Have you overloaded any methods of TransactionScope used above?

Comment: Hi, Yes i have tried on the option strict, but I got no idea why its showing 28 errors which is not related to my current error. I passed the function and it was transaction competed sucessfully and when it comes to end using the transaction is nothing and it throws the error. Overloaded meaning? –  valliammai muthiah 4 hours ago

Comment: From Microsoft: "`The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the End Using statement if the TransactionScope object created the transaction.`" This seems to be the step that is causing your error. I don't see any actual transaction code above. I assume it's in the CreatePrescriptionHistory method? Please post that code as it would appear to be the culprit for your error.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have add the CreatePrescriptionHistory code below:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone I have found the answer where I need to change RequiresNew to Required.